# How to set the BAccount to updated so that sales force integration picks up that there was a update

Tags: salesforce, acumatica

Good day

The SalesForce feature that can be enabled under licensing(Enable/Disable Features) integrates with SalesForce. It picked up that there was a change in the Business Account and sets the account to Modified locally(This can be seen in a new Tab in the Business Account).

I created a new field UsrCreditLimit in the BAccount. This is to move the Credit limit to the Business account so that the standard SalesForce integration can see the field.

The problem I have is when I update the field the SalesForce code to trigger the sync doesn't happen; The Field changes but the sync doesn't happen.
I have tested if I manually change the field the code does execute to trigger the sync. I have also tried opening a new Graph in the code to update the field without any luck.

Is there a way to set the BAaccount to Updated using the SalesForce dll/code.

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        public delegate void PersistDelegate();
        [PXOverride]
        public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
        { 
            
            Customer curCustomer = this.Base.CurrentCustomer.Select();

            CR.BAccountExt curBAccountExt = curCustomer.GetExtension<CR.BAccountExt>();
            curBAccountExt.UsrCreditLimit = curCustomer.CreditLimit.Value.ToString();
            baseMethod();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your code correctly ...

Since a customer is a BAccount (it actually inherits from BAccount), why don't you also add your custom field to the Customer? and then it should be just a matter of updating this custom field. No need to call Save.PressButton again.

Comment: Hi Joseph. I have tried what you suggested. The salesforce code still doesn't trigger. FYI I did edit the question, think it explains my issue a bit better now

Comment: Try calling SetValue ext here: curBAccountExt.UsrCreditLimit or perhaps calling Cache.update afterwards